# For Loop In Verilog Does Not Converge

Tags: for-loop, verilog, vivado

I'm attempting to using a for loop to count the repeated leading bit in a 32-bit number. For this, I am doing:

```
input[31:0] A;
output reg result;
Integer i;
for (i = 31; i > -1; i = i - 1) begin
    if (A[i] == 0) begin
        result = result + 1;
    end
    else if (A[i] == 1) begin
        i = -1;
    end
end
```

However, when I synthesize the program, I receive a warning saying that the program does not converge. Am I using the for loop wrong? Before this I used i >= 0 and even used a while instead but it doesn't change the outcome. I would appreciate any help. Should I set result to 0 before running the loop?

Comment: did you mean `i = i - 1` by a chance?

Comment: Yes, sorry. That was a copy error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A[i] == 1` makes number of iterations non-deterministic and causes synthesis to fail. The way around it is letting the loop to unroll till the end and use a conditional variable to handle your calculations. Something like the following:

```
input[31:0] A;
output reg result;
Integer i;
reg flag;

flag = 0;
for (i = 31; i > -1; i = i - 1) begin
    if (flag == 0 && A[i] == 0) begin
        result = result + 1;
    end
    else if (A[i] == 1) begin
        flag = 1;
    end
end
```

I assume that it was some type of a flop logic, since in any case this would produce state elements. So, you need to use correct nbas for result and flag.

Answer (score 0):

For synthesis for loops must converge during COMPILE time. Your condition of `A[i]==1` can not be determined at compile time so the loops goes from 32 to 2^31-1 before it ends.

Verilog is an HDL, which in many aspects is totally different from standard computer languages.

Comment: How can I implement that sort of check? Should I be using a while loop instead?